# module 'keras.engine.base_layer' has no attribute 'BaseRandomLayer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The code returns an error whenever i run it, im running a conda enviroment, and ive tried installing tensorflow, keras, and layers multiple times, but none of them change anything, ive tried installing it through pip and conda multiple times, and i keep getting this error:

```
  from keras import __version__
File "D:\Miniconda\envs\py39tensor\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
  from keras import models
File "D:\Miniconda\envs\py39tensor\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 20, in <module>
  from keras import metrics as metrics_module
File "D:\Miniconda\envs\py39tensor\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py", line 26, in <module>
  from keras import activations
File "D:\Miniconda\envs\py39tensor\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py", line 20, in <module>
  from keras.layers import advanced_activations
File "D:\Miniconda\envs\py39tensor\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
  from keras.layers.preprocessing.image_preprocessing import CenterCrop
File "D:\Miniconda\envs\py39tensor\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\preprocessing\image_preprocessing.py", line 24, in <module>
  from keras.preprocessing import image as image_preprocessing
File "D:\Miniconda\envs\py39tensor\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  from keras.utils import all_utils as utils
File "D:\Miniconda\envs\py39tensor\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\all_utils.py", line 34, in <module>
  from keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model
File "D:\Miniconda\envs\py39tensor\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\multi_gpu_utils.py", line 20, in <module>
  from keras.layers.core import Lambda
File "D:\Miniconda\envs\py39tensor\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
  from keras.layers.core.dropout import Dropout
File "D:\Miniconda\envs\py39tensor\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core\dropout.py", line 26, in <module>
  class Dropout(base_layer.BaseRandomLayer):
AttributeError: module 'keras.engine.base_layer' has no attribute 'BaseRandomLayer'
```

code:

```py
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x, test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using python 3.7. One possible solution would be to use a python=3.8 conda environment.

Also, you have a mistake in your code above:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x, test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

Change it to

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

Then, everything shall work.

Answer (score 0):

The BaseRandomLayer class is no longer available in TensorFlow 2.8 and above. It was removed in TensorFlow 2.7.0. If you are trying to import it, you will get an AttributeError.

To fix this, you can downgrade your TensorFlow version to 2.7 or below. Or, you can use the keras library, which includes a BaseRandomLayer class.

Here is an example of how to import BaseRandomLayer from keras:

```
from keras.engine import base_layer    
layer = base_random_layer.BaseRandomLayer()
```